# Create new column in pandas if list contain any string of another sublist

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this df:

```
id words
1  ['apple', 'banana', 'grape']
2  ['apple', 'banana', 'chocolate']
3  ['grape', 'popcorn', 'chocolate']
4  ['grape', 'apple', 'popcorn']
```

How can I create a new column checking if 'chocolate' or 'popcorn' is inside each row-list. I've tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
sublist = ['chocolate', 'popcorn']

df['boolean_check'] = df['words'].isin(sublist).any()
```

also tried:

```
 df['boolean_check'] = np.where(df['words'].isin(sublist).any(), True, False)
```

expected result:

```
id words                             boolean_check
1  ['apple', 'banana', 'grape']      False
2  ['apple', 'banana', 'chocolate']  True
3  ['grape', 'popcorn', 'chocolate'] True
4  ['grape', 'apple', 'popcorn']     True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `explode`

```
np.where(df['words'].explode().isin(sublist).any(level=0), True, False)
```

Comment: No need for np.where() ?